# How to parse XML using ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: iphone, .net

I have implemented web services in .net. Now i want to parse data and display it in uitabel view using ASIHTTPRequest.

Can you give me advice?

Comment: try checking my last question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456076/how-do-i-detect-a-http-response-parse-the-xml-and-save-to-a-nsstring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456076/how-do-i-detect-a-http-response-parse-the-xml-and-save-to-a-nsstring)

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373609/simplexml-way-of-parsing-in-objective-c-for-iphone-app/1375352#1375352